# Jquery: function on .blur() of form, not elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, blur

I've searched around the community, and see there is a lot of guidance on how to make on(blur(function)) or on(focusout(function)) for form elements, but I have not seen a blur element kick in when a form itself loses focus. I want that kind of behavior that relies on two fields being updated before submit, but if I valid on a field onblur() it will give a false error, because the user didn't have the chance to update the other field.

Here is the code of my basic concept:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").blur(function(){
        alert("This form has lost its focus.");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Enter your name: <input type="text">
Enter your age: <input type="text">
</form>
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I have the .ready statement focus on "input" instead, [it works fine](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_blur_alert), but is totally unresponsive when I want the document to monitor the overall form instead. Any Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: a form itself can't have or lose focus; you can only check the fields within.  Instead, use the onblur of each form field to provide an error message for only that field, and the onsubmit handler of the form to validate all fields and display all errors as needed.

Comment: @andi "a form itself can't have or lose focus" Strictly speaking that is not entirely true. By default a form will not gain focus but any element can have a `tabindex` attribute added to it and then it can gain focus both by a mouse click and the tab key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are looking for is not `blur` it's `focusout`. If we bind a `focusout` event to the form itself, the handler will be called whenever focus is lost on any element inside the form.

Also note that the `tabindex` attributes I added to the various elements have nothing to do with this code working. They were added because an erroneous comment was made on your post claiming that forms can't be focused.

From here [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

> The tabindex global attribute indicates if its element can be focused, and if/where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the Tab key, hence the name). It accepts an integer as a value, with different results depending on the integer's value:
>
> - A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation. Mostly useful to create accessible widgets with JavaScript.

As you can see any element can receive focus. It's just that only some elements **will** receive focus by default (anchors, inputs, buttons, etc...) without setting a `tabindex` for them. In the example below, if you click on the "Enter your name" text you will see the form itself gain focus. You can then tab to the inputs, then the div and finally the span. All of them receiving focus in turn.

```js
$('#theForm').on('focusout', function(e) {
  // do what you want/need to do here
  console.log('Form has lost focus');
});
```

```css
#theDiv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="theForm" tabindex="1">
Enter your name: <input type="text" tabindex="2">
Enter your age: <input type="text" tabindex="3">
</form>
<div id="theDiv" tabindex="4"></div>
<span tabindex="5">Some Text</span>
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>
```

Comment: Aww nice down vote. Did I hwurt somebody's little feelings?

Comment: Thanks for the addition with tabindex and focusout! It looks like it runs itself recursively if you click off the field and onto the form itself, though. I guess I'll take the lesson and just apply specific tests for each field that needs it.

Comment: @NathanielMacIver It is just a simplistic example, the point of which is that the `focusout` event trigger on all the elements contained including the form itself. The problem now is that it triggers even if you focus another element in the form because the previous element in the form just lost focus. You would need to add logic to tell if the element getting focus is still within the form and suppress whatever action you want to do until the entire form loses focus.